# asterisk ivr no dealing tone

Tags: asterisk, ivr

I am setting up IVR and encountered following trouble there is no dealing tone when client gets to "Dial", it just silently dialing. How to fix this?

```
exten => s,1,Background(custom/welcome-msg)
exten => s,n,WaitExten(10)
exten => s,n,Dial(SIP/0773,20)

exten => _X,1,Read(NUMBER,,4,n,,10)
exten => _X,n,Dial(SIP/${NUMBER},20)
exten => _X,n,HangUp()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need add 'r' option in params.

```
exten => _X,n,Dial(SIP/${NUMBER},20,r)
```

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Dial+Application